# Table to Chart and Chart to Table update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, charts

Can any one help me out..

I wanted to have a Line Chart .. The Data to be loaded from sqlserver to that Line Chart..
One can drag the Line chart values and adjust them..

> I am trying this using ChartDirectory tool.

[Link](http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery.html)

Once after adjustment of line chart, the Values to be updated to the same table..

Hopefully this makes sense, if not let me know.

```
Is there any tools available for this ??
```

[Like This I want](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/)

Answer (score 0):

you should try this free online tool - [www.cloudyexcel.com/excel-to-graph/](http://cloudyexcel.com/excel-to-graph/)

[image]